# Accessing disabled matrix blocks in a plugin

Tags: plugin-development

I've got a plugin which needs to be able to access all the blocks in a matrix - regardless of if the blocks are enabled or disabled.

The entry objects returned by the likes of `craft()->entries->getEntryById` only seem to include blocks in the matrix fields which are enabled.

Is there a way to access this information through a service - or do I need to work out how this is handled in the control panel (which does show disabled matrix blocks)?

Answer (score 2):

Something like this should do it:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::MatrixBlock);
$criteria->status = null;
$find = $criteria->find();
```

Setting `status` to null will return all elements regardless of their status.

Comment: The difficultly I'm having with the manual approach is finding the right criteria to restrict the results to the matrix block content for a specific entry id. I can query the db directly - but following the chain of relationships is proving difficult.

Answer (score 1):

If you already have an entry object, and know the handle for the Matrix field, you can use:

```
$criteria = craft()->elements->getCriteria(ElementType::MatrixBlock);
$criteria->fieldId = craft()->fields->getFieldByHandle('matrixFieldHandle')->id;
$criteria->ownerId = $entry->id;
$criteria->status = null;
$blocks = $criteria->find();
```